# Is there a way to localise a package in Perl - database handle issues?

Tags: perl, dbi

I need to instantiate a new $dbh using DBI.

My objects usually have a $dbh present when they're created.

When I try to create a new $dbh using

```
my $dbh = MyLib::Connect();
```

and after performing some DB operations doing

```
$dbh->disconnect();
```

my downstream code's $dbh is closed. Is there a way to get what I'm after? I've seen some example code that does two DBI->connect(...) calls but using the same code as an example produces the same result - it's like MyLib is caching the returned $dbh value.

Example code:

```
package MyLib;
sub DoConnect { 
  ...
  my $dbh = DBI->connect(...);
  return($dbh)
}

package Object;
sub GetData {
  my ($id) = @_;
  my $dbh = MyLib::DoConnect(); # This should be separate
  ...
  $dbh->commit()
  $dbh->disconnect();
  return($someData);
}

package AnotherObject;
sub DoSomething {
  my ($self) = @_; 
  # $self had a dbh set on instantiation with MyLib::DoConnect();
  my $newData = Object::GetData($self->id);
  my $moreData = GetDataUsingDBH($self->dbh); # the dbh is closed!!!
}
```

Is what I need to do possible without starting a separate thread (which I can't guarantee will finish before GetDataUsingDBH is called). Should I do a system call to an external program to wait for it to finish? Does my question even make sense?

Comment: The database handle used by `Object::GetData` is independent of any other because it is declared with `my`. Calling `disconnect` on it cannot affect any other handle. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: That goes back to my question of localizing the MyLib package which is returning the shared database handle that's causing the issue.

Comment: Hmm, all my DoConnect does is a `DBI->connect(...)` -- I have no idea why it's returning the existing handle.

I guess I'll kickoff a subprocess to get the data I need, but it feels so entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidCrane: I don't think you understand me. Two separate calls to `MyLib::DoConnect` will return two distinct and independent database handles. Disconnecting the handle created in `Object::GetData` will not affect the one created by `AnotherObject::new` (or whatever you have called it). Your diagnosis is wrong, unless you're using `connect_cached` instead of a simple `connect`.

Comment: @Borodin nevertheless, that is what he says is happening; see my answer

Comment: What's `$self->dbh`? You never showed that being populated!

Comment: It's an attribute on my object. It returns the dbh established in my new()  call is all. Again it was created via DoConnect.

Comment: Please provide a mininal, runnable demonstration of the problem.

Comment: You mentioned threads. Are you already using threads?

Comment: @ikegami I'm not currently using threads.

Comment: The reason for these questions is that the answer to what you asked is: Use exactly the code you describe because it works. Something you didn't mention is what's causing you problems. Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem.

Comment: what do you get when you `print $DBI::connect_via;`?

Comment: "connect" comes out.

I've just tried connecting to a separate database. I can query data that I know is only in the new database successfully but when I disconnect my other DBH close as well.

I'm frustrated and baffled at this point.

Comment: How about just removing the disconnect call?

Comment: Create a simple script that just calls MyLib::DoConnect twice and see if it is the same handle.  If it isn't, add stuff to match your real code a little at a time until it breaks.   If it is, step through it in the Perl debugger and see if it is actually calling DBI::connect or something else is getting in the way somehow.

Comment: What version of DBI?  What database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I setup my DBHs to be shared by all of my objects in the executable so I don't have to instantiate one DBH and pass it around to my objects manually - this ruined the behavior I was expecting when I actually needed to do this.

Thanks for all of your help, folks - learned a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

The approach you describe works fine.

```
package MyLib;

use DBI qw( );

sub DoConnect {
   return DBI->connect(
      'dbi:SQLite:foo.sqlite3', undef, undef,
      { PrintError=>0, RaiseError=>1 },
   );
}


package Object;

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = bless({}, $class);
   return $self;
}

sub GetData {
   my $dbh = MyLib::DoConnect();
   $dbh->disconnect();
}


package AnotherObject;

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = bless({}, $class);
   $self->{dbh} = MyLib::DoConnect();
   return $self;
}

sub DoSomething {
   my ($self) = @_;
   return $self->{dbh}->selectrow_array("SELECT 'abc'");
}


package main;

my $ao = AnotherObject->new();
my $o = Object->new();
$o->GetData();
print $ao->DoSomething(), "\n";
```

Output:

```
abc
```

Something else you didn't mention is causing the problems.

Comment: I'm stuck using an older version of DBI - while I can't find this in any patch notes or bug reports, it seems that a disconnect on any of my database handles closes ALL of my database handles.

Since my DBHs are cleaned by my process flow later anyway, I can create and commit on a second dbh without affecting the first and know they will be closed. If I start getting messages about a missing explicit DISCONNECT later I'll know where to look.

DBI 1.607

Answer (score -1):

Are you certain DoConnect is calling DBI->connect, not DBI->connect_cached, or something else that is caching database handles?

If so, I'm guessing you have Apache::DBI loaded and are running under mod_perl (or at any rate have `$ENV{MOD_PERL}` set), which causes DBI->connect to use Apache::DBI to cache connections.

You can tell DBI to *not* do this by calling connect with a `dbi_connect_method` attribute:

```
DBI->connect( $data_source, $username, $auth, {
    'dbi_connect_method' => 'connect',
} );
```

(which would require you to pass something into your DoConnect saying that's what you want).

That is the documented way; an undocumented way that may work for you is to locally set the variable that DBI uses as the default for that attribute:

```
# This should be separate
my $dbh = do { local $DBI::connect_via = 'connect'; MyLib::DoConnect() };
```

(I guess it is possible even if you don't have `$ENV{MOD_PERL}` set when you load DBI that your code is already setting $DBI::connect_via to 'connect_cached' or some other package and that is causing your trouble.)

Another approach, if you don't actually need to use the two database handles at the same time, would be to just remove the disconnect call.  When $dbh goes out of scope, if there are no other copies of that database handle around, it will be closed; explicitly calling disconnect isn't necessary.